# hide the link text when href value is empty

Tags: jquery, xslt, hide, anchor

I need to hide the Link text. if href is empty, hide the Link Text. The XSL code made this a little complicated.

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:if test="not(contains(@WEBSITE,'://'))">http://</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@WEBSITE" />          
    </xsl:attribute>
    <span class="website">VISIT WEBSITE</span>
```

So if the  element that gets the href value from @WEBSITE is not containing URL, I need the hide text inside the Span Class'website'. How do i do this in jquery?

```
$('.website').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).prev(find('a')).text() == '') { 
$(this).hide(); 
    } 
});
```

is not working

Comment: Have you tried something or just read the jquery documentation to solve **your** issue?

Comment: @am not i am, thanks for the link of "what have you tried".

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `find` and replace `text` with `attr` and it should work

```
$('.website').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).prev('a').attr('href') == '') { 
        $(this).hide(); 
    } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y3dPz/